# Receive shutdown broadcast notification in desktop (GNU/Linux, Gnome)

Tags: linux, gnome, shutdown, gnu

When

```
# shutdown +5
```

is run all the terminals (including pseudo terminals) are sent broadcast messages saying system is about to go down.

Is it possible for user to receive this in the form of OSD or system tray notification so that he will be informed even if he is not running any terminal emulator or running it but minimized it and working with something else?

Comment: There's a guy who hacked one together - his mailing list post is [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=433960).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Tools like *wall* or *shutdown* write the messages to each "user" entry in */run/utmp*, and a fake entry can easily be added.

I have written a tool [wallnotify](https://github.com/grawity/wallnotify) to redisplay these broadcasts as GNOME notifications. It works as long as you have read the *README* file.

Comment: Great. They should include this in distro's by default. Or at least in repos.

Comment: @Akilan: This is only a temporary fix. I'd rather have shutdown use DBus for notifications... but feel free to suggest the program to your distro's developers.